# How to override second time a method of mocked object using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, java-14

`SQLException`  is thrown in `overrideMockedDsConnectionAction` when calling `case CONNECTED` after `case DISCONNECTED`. Mockito calls `ds.getConnection()` that throws the exception when it is expected to override previous behaviour. How to make it work?

**Integration test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class MyServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
    
    @SpyBean
    DataSource ds;
    
    private void overrideMockedDsConnectionAction(ACTION overrideWith) throws SQLException {
        switch (overrideWith) {
            case CONNECTED -> given(ds.getConnection()).willCallRealMethod();
            case DISCONNECTED -> given(ds.getConnection()).willThrow(new SQLException("DataSource is DISCONNECTED"));
        }
    }
    
    
    @Test
    public void example() {
    
        try {
            overrideMockedDsConnectionAction(ACTION.DISCONNECTED);
            // call myService method that will use DataSource to persist data
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
    
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(waitTime);
    
            overrideMockedDsConnectionAction(ACTION.CONNECTED);
            log.info("ConnectionState  -> CONNECTED");
        
            // 2nd call of myService method that will use DataSource to persist data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried chaining `when(triggersDictionary.getById(10L)).thenThrow(new SQLException("DataSource is DISCONNECTED")).thenCallRealMethod()`?

Comment: Are you sure that the SQLException is not from the real implementation? Could you please add the full stack trace

Comment: @Arnaud Claudel, if I change it to `case DISCONNECTED -> given(ds.getConnection()).willThrow(new RuntimeException("RuntimeException: DataSource is DISCONNECTED"));` then I have exactly that `RuntimeException`

Comment: @Vasiliy Sarzhynskyi, what is `triggersDictionary`?

Comment: it was just an example. in your case `when(ds.getConnection())`